# How to use notifyDataSetChanged with SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am using a SQLite table (using the DAO pattern) and a `SimpleAdapter` to display a `ListView`, where each row contains a couple of `String`.
I set a `ItemClickListener` on the `ListView` to delete the clicked row, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
                Long idSelected = (Long) element0.get("ID");
                daoMessage.delete(idSelected);
                simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

The row is actually removed from the SQL table. However, the ListView doesn't update and still shows the row. I guess I'm missing something, but what?

Answer (score 1):

As much i can understand your problem, i can see that you are removing a record from database.. right?
Problem you are doing at your end is that you have provided a cloned data set from database.So you have to options to get it done

`1)You also need to remove that record from cloned dataset used for adapter as you are doing seprately for database`

`2)You need to override notifyDataSetChanged() method and can do step 1 here or can fetch again available data from db using DAO.`